# MediaPlayer HLS Playback failed after change source

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, android-mediaplayer, hlsl

I'm writing an app for HLS streams. I'm using **3 instances of MediaPlayers**, which playing different HLS **at the same time**. 
Sometimes that working well, but when I put any different adress to one of mediaPlayer instances using:      `mediaPlayerInstance1.setDataSource(adress)`

the `mediaPlayerInstance1` dosn't works properly - it shows only black screen sometimes with or without sound. Wnen black screen is on the one of MediaPlayer and I reload other mediaPlayerInstance (with the same adress that previously worked) other instance of media player can also show black screen (but not always).

When I try to start **only 1 instance of mediaPlayer** with previously adress that doesn't works (with 3 instances of MPs), mediaPlayer works fine, then stream seems good.

When black screen shows without sound I get error:
`E/MediaPlayer(12312): error (1, -2147483648)`

When black screen happens with sound there aren't any errors.

I catched only 2 types of errors from **"All messages(no filter)"**

(*Please notice that these errors doesn't happen when there is only one instance of MediaPlayer*)

First:

```
02-11 12:27:38.980: E/NuPlayer(1972): Buffering Start
    02-11 12:27:38.980: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1246] notify (0x42c97da8, 200, 701, 0)
    02-11 12:27:38.980: V/NuPlayer(1972): scanning sources haveAudio=0, haveVideo=0
    02-11 12:27:38.985: V/MediaPlayer(14245): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
    02-11 12:27:38.985: W/MediaPlayer(14245): info/warning (701, 0)
    02-11 12:27:38.985: V/MediaPlayer(14245): callback application
    02-11 12:27:38.985: V/MediaPlayer(14245): back from callback
    02-11 12:27:38.995: I/System.out(14245): onPrepared() 0
    02-11 12:27:38.995: I/MediaPlayer(14245): Info (701,0)
    02-11 12:27:38.995: I/MediaPlayer: 0(14245): (701, 0)
    02-11 12:27:39.085: V/NuPlayer(1972): scanning sources haveAudio=0, haveVideo=0
    02-11 12:27:39.085: I/ESQueue(1972): found AAC codec config (22050 Hz, 1 channels)
    02-11 12:27:39.085: I/avc_utils(1972): found AVC codec config (320 x 240, Baseline-profile level 1.3)
    02-11 12:27:39.085: I/AnotherPacketSource(1972): resize MAX Resolution[1280 x 960]
    02-11 12:27:39.190: V/NuPlayer(1972): scanning sources haveAudio=0, haveVideo=0
    02-11 12:27:39.190: D/NuPlayer(1972): set HLS for decoder
    02-11 12:27:39.190: D/NuPlayer(1972): set HLS for decoder
    02-11 12:27:39.195: D/OMX(1972): SendBroadCasting VIDEO_PLAYBACK_START
    02-11 12:27:39.200: E/NuPlayer(1972): kWhatComponentConfigured is =audio
    02-11 12:27:39.200: E/ACodec(1972): Before getExtensionIndex.
    02-11 12:27:39.200: E/ACodec(1972): Before setConfig.
    02-11 12:27:39.200: E/ACodec(1972): After finishing the DRC..
    02-11 12:27:39.200: I/OMX(1972): width (1280), height (960), fps (15)
    02-11 12:27:39.205: E/OMX(1972):  setParam  sum(3314688) > max resolution(3010560)
    02-11 12:27:39.205: E/ACodec(1972):  configureCodec multi window instance fail  appPid : 14245
    02-11 12:27:39.205: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(1) -> Dest(2)
    02-11 12:27:39.205: I/NuPlayer(1972): componentName = OMX.SEC.avc.dec
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814): readBundle: bad magic number
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814): readBundle: trace = java.lang.RuntimeException
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at android.os.Bundle.readFromParcelInner(Bundle.java:1677)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:83)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1579)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1564)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:371)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/Bundle(3814):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/ACodec(1972): [OMX.SEC.avc.dec] configureCodec returning error -38
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/NuPlayer(1972): Received error from video decoder, aborting playback.
    02-11 12:27:39.210: E/NuPlayer(1972): internalError -38
```

Second:

```
 02-11 12:06:56.785: E/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.785: E/Surface(1972): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
    02-11 12:06:56.785: E/NuPlayer(1972): Received error from video decoder, aborting playback.
    02-11 12:06:56.785: E/NuPlayer(1972): internalError -19
    02-11 12:06:56.800: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(4566): onReceive() - ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
    02-11 12:06:56.815: D/PhoneStatusBar(4566): mSettingsPanelGravity = 55
    02-11 12:06:56.825: E/NuPlayer(1972): video track encountered an error (-2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.825: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1237] notify (0x47c2ebb0, 100, 1, -2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.825: V/MediaPlayer(12312): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
    02-11 12:06:56.825: E/MediaPlayer(12312): error (1, -2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.825: V/MediaPlayer(12312): callback application
    02-11 12:06:56.825: V/MediaPlayer(12312): back from callback
    02-11 12:06:56.825: E/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.825: E/Surface(1972): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
    02-11 12:06:56.825: E/NuPlayer(1972): Received error from video decoder, aborting playback.
    02-11 12:06:56.825: E/NuPlayer(1972): internalError -19
    02-11 12:06:56.830: I/SurfaceFlinger(1968): id=1216 Removed NainActivit (4/10)
    02-11 12:06:56.830: I/SurfaceFlinger(1968): id=1216 Removed NainActivit (-2/10)
    02-11 12:06:56.830: V/WindowManager(3814): Window{433336d8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
    02-11 12:06:56.835: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12312): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    02-11 12:06:56.835: D/PowerManagerService(3814): [api] [s] userActivity : event: 0 flags: 0 (uid: 1000 pid: 3814)
    02-11 12:06:56.835: D/PowerManagerService(3814): [api] release WakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=3814 (0x0)
    02-11 12:06:56.835: D/PowerManagerService(3814): [api] applyWakeLockFlagsOnReleaseLocked : userActivityNoUpdateLocked is called : SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=3814, ws=WorkSource{10104}) (elapsedTime=155029)
    02-11 12:06:56.840: E/MediaPlayer(12312): Error (1,-2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.840: E/MediaPlayer: 2(12312): (1, -2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.840: W/System.err(12312): unknown error
    02-11 12:06:56.840: V/WindowManager(3814): Window{433336d8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
    02-11 12:06:56.845: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(4566): checkOverflow(462), More:false, Req:false Child:1
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(12312): reset
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/MediaPlayer(12312): reset
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1235] reset
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): kWhatReset
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): performDecoderShutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1235] notify (0x428dbd20, 200, 701, 0)
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): renderer audio flush completed.
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): renderer video flush completed.
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): decoder video flush completed
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): initiating video decoder shutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): decoder audio flush completed
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/NuPlayer(1972): initiating audio decoder shutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.850: V/MediaPlayer(12312): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
    02-11 12:06:56.855: D/OMX(1972): SendBroadCasting VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.855: D/WFDService(3814): intent recieved android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.855: E/WFDService(3814): FHD : android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.855: V/NuPlayer(1972): video shutdown completed
    02-11 12:06:56.855: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
    02-11 12:06:56.860: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): audio shutdown completed
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): both audio and video are flushed now.
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): reset completed
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): performReset
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): onDisconnectComplete() mState = 0
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): ~ChromiumHTTPDataSource()
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.865: E/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.865: E/Surface(1972): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
    02-11 12:06:56.865: E/NuPlayer(1972): video track encountered an error (-2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1237] notify (0x47c2ebb0, 100, 1, -2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.865: E/NuPlayer(1972): Received error from video decoder, aborting playback.
    02-11 12:06:56.865: E/NuPlayer(1972): internalError -19
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayer(12312): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
    02-11 12:06:56.865: E/MediaPlayer(12312): error (1, -2147483648)
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayer(12312): callback application
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayer(12312): notify(200, 701, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(12312): reset
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayer(12312): reset
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1236] reset
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): kWhatReset
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): performDecoderShutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1236] notify (0x458f9038, 200, 701, 0)
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): renderer audio flush completed.
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): renderer video flush completed.
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): decoder video flush completed
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/NuPlayer(1972): initiating video decoder shutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.865: V/MediaPlayer(12312): back from callback
    02-11 12:06:56.865: D/OMX(1972): SendBroadCasting VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): decoder audio flush completed
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): initiating audio decoder shutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.870: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
    02-11 12:06:56.870: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): audio shutdown completed
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): video shutdown completed
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): both audio and video are flushed now.
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): reset completed
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/NuPlayer(1972): performReset
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.870: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): onDisconnectComplete() mState = 0
    02-11 12:06:56.870: D/WFDService(3814): intent recieved android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.870: E/WFDService(3814): FHD : android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.875: V/MediaPlayer(12312): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
    02-11 12:06:56.875: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): ~ChromiumHTTPDataSource()
    02-11 12:06:56.875: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): Client(1235) destructor pid = 12312
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): disconnect(1235) from pid 12312
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/AudioSink(1972): +++ close
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/LvOutput(1972): initCheck: 0
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/LvOutput(1972): detachEffects: detach processing for output 2, stream 3, session 2211
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/LvOutput(1972): detachEffects: no output processing was attached to this stream
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1972): stopOutput() output 2, stream 3, session 2211
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1972): changeRefCount() stream 3, count 2
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1972): releaseOutput() 2
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/AudioSink(1972): --- close
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayer(12312): notify(200, 701, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(12312): reset
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayer(12312): reset
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1237] reset
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/NuPlayer(1972): kWhatReset
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/NuPlayer(1972): performDecoderShutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.880: E/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] query: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.880: E/ACodec(1972): [OMX.SEC.avc.dec] NATIVE_WINDOW_MIN_UNDEQUEUED_BUFFERS query failed: No such device (19)
    02-11 12:06:56.880: E/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayerService(1972): [1237] notify (0x47c2ebb0, 200, 701, 0)
    02-11 12:06:56.880: E/ACodec(1972): dequeueBuffer failed.
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/NuPlayer(1972): renderer audio flush completed.
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/NuPlayer(1972): renderer video flush completed.
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/NuPlayer(1972): decoder video flush completed
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/NuPlayer(1972): initiating video decoder shutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.880: V/MediaPlayer(12312): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
    02-11 12:06:56.880: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
    02-11 12:06:56.890: V/NuPlayer(1972): decoder audio flush completed
    02-11 12:06:56.890: V/NuPlayer(1972): initiating audio decoder shutdown
    02-11 12:06:56.890: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
    02-11 12:06:56.890: W/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.890: W/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.890: W/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.890: W/BufferQueue(1968): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
    02-11 12:06:56.890: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
    02-11 12:06:56.890: V/NuPlayer(1972): audio shutdown completed
    02-11 12:06:56.895: I/SEC_BASE_COMP(1972): SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
    02-11 12:06:56.900: D/OMX(1972): SendBroadCasting VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/NuPlayer(1972): video shutdown completed
    02-11 12:06:56.900: D/WFDService(3814): intent recieved android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.900: E/WFDService(3814): FHD : android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/NuPlayer(1972): both audio and video are flushed now.
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/NuPlayer(1972): reset completed
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/NuPlayer(1972): performReset
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): onDisconnectComplete() mState = 0
    02-11 12:06:56.900: E/LiveSession(1972): fail readAt[-107]
    02-11 12:06:56.900: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.900: E/LiveSession(1972): fetchFailed--mSeekPending is 0
    02-11 12:06:56.900: E/LiveSession(1972): failed to fetch .ts segment at url 'http://ndr_fs-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ndrfs_nds@119224/segment139211680_3712_av-b.ts?sd=10&rebase=on', err[-107]
    02-11 12:06:56.905: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): ~ChromiumHTTPDataSource()
    02-11 12:06:56.905: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(1972): disconnect()
    02-11 12:06:56.910: W/ALooperRoster(1972): failed to deliver message. Target handler 3790 registered, but object gone.
```

How to resolve these problems? 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I have never worked with HLS, or tried switching between multiple `MediaPlayer` instances. I would expect what you want to only work with `TextureView`, though, as multiple `SurfaceViews` have long been a problem area. I am guessing that you are already using `TextureView`, as HLS support is relatively recent to Android IIRC. But, beyond that, I am afraid that I have no particular advice -- sorry!